# NSF letter of intent to collaborate w/ industry partner

Tags: funding, industry, nsf

Currently a university is pursuing an NSF grant with an industry partner, who might participate in a minor role. The university has jointly appointed faculty with the partner. These faculty would be working as unfunded collaborators on the grant, as would, potentially, some other members of their respective teams outside the university. The faculty cannot sign a letter of intent to collaborate on behalf of the partner(ship).

We'd like to include this letter of intent to collaborate, but using the NSF's suggested formatting is unlikely to pass the partner's legal checks and balances within the time remaining. (They likely will want to review the entire proposal, even though their duties are limited to a pre-existing collaboration agreement.) If we could replace the NSF's suggested language (see [here](https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappg17_1/pappg_2.jsp#IIC2j)) with language that specifically details the duties of the partner, making it self-contained, this would potentially not be an issue. [Here](https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappg17_1/pappg_2.jsp#IIC2div), the NSF seems to insist that you *must* use their recommended format.

Has anyone had experience with a similar situation and, if so, was there any freedom to adjust the language?